# Can I travel to Spain using a Greek Schengen visa even if I don't want to stay in Greece at all?

Tags: visas, schengen, spain, greece

I want to travel to Spain however the requirements state that my UK residence permit be valid for 3 months after intended date of departure from the Schengen area. I'll only have 1 month left when I return. The Greek rules just states I need to have a valid Uk residence permit. Could I apply through the Greek consulate but then use the visa to travel to Spain or do I at least need to touch down in Greece?

Comment: @Dirty-flow Why do people often point to this question that does not even begin to address the issues raised here? If you must find related questions, http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26459/applying-for-a-schengen-visa-in-another-country-than-my-main-destination or http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26939/can-i-use-my-schengen-visa-for-a-completely-different-purpose-and-entry-point are the only ones that make sense (but there are also important differences).

Comment: @Relaxed the accepted answer says: "When deciding which country to apply for a visa, this is determined by which country you're spending the most time according to your filed itinerary." So - the OP should apply to the Spanish consulate. The rest is a workaround that can go wrong.

Comment: @Dirty-flow Maybe but, beside being rather incomplete compared to the other answers I mentioned, it's not what **the question** is about (the only things that matters when deciding on duplicates). Incidentally, the rest is not a “workaround”, it's outright fraud.

Comment: @Relaxed The Stack Exchange standard for identifying a duplicate is if the applicable answer can be found in the other question's answers, not that the questions themselves be interchangeable word-for-word.

Comment: @choster Since when and more importantly why? I always heard otherwise from different people, including mods on this site. The blog and help center even suggest that some duplicate *questions* are OK. And I am not talking about being interchangeable “word-for-word”, I am talking about entirely different things (i.e. using a visa you already have vs. applying for one). The *applicable* answers therefore do *not* address the question in any way (the bit quoted by dirty-flow, while relevant, does not actually apply to the earlier question, which is about someone who already has a visa…).

Comment: None of the questions linked address the present question because is **not** about using a visa you already have, applying to another consulate because it's closer or using a *multiple-entry* visa for another purpose.

Comment: @Relaxed The rule of thumb I was pointed to is now at *[When is a duplicate question not a duplicate?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12182)*

Comment: @choster I had read this page before and it certainly does not suggest anything like what you implied earlier. If you read carefully, you will notice that the *question* themselves have to be similar and the answers must be *exactly the same*. Neither apply here and vaguely related answers are certainly not enough on their own.

Comment: I would recommend to read Joel Spolsky's answer here: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/698/we-need-to-be-more-careful-about-closing-questions-as-duplicates

TO cite the most important parts: "Remember that a duplicate answer is not the same as a duplicate question.

Close duplicate QUESTIONS. Don't close a question that *happens to have the same answer as another question."

Answer (score 4):

No, in principle you cannot. If you only want to go to Spain, you should apply to the Spanish consulate and the Greek consulate should refuse to consider your application (see [Applying for a Schengen visa in another country than my main destination](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26459/applying-for-a-schengen-visa-in-another-country-than-my-main-destination)). If you somehow do get a Greek visa to travel to Spain and the Spanish border guards notice it, they can annul the visa and deny entry (see [Schengen visa requirements and "validation"](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6609/schengen-visa-requirements-and-validation/27633#27633)).

You can however enter Spain with a visa issued by the Greek consulate (see [Should my first trip be to the country which issued my Schengen Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-me-schengen-visa)) or even travel to other Schengen countries without going through Greece at all (see [Does a multiple-entry Schengen visa allow visiting other Schengen countries later, without going via the issuing country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9646/does-a-multiple-entry-schengen-visa-allow-visiting-other-schengen-countries-late?rq=1)). But that's mostly relevant if you have a legitimate reason to have a Greek visa in the first place (e.g. Greece is your main destination or you have a multiple entry circulation visa because you go to Greece regularly) and *not* for a single-entry visa obtained for another trip.

In practice, you could still get away with it, especially if you buy a ticket from Spain to Greece so as to make it look like Greece is your main destination. But this would obviously be a form of fraud and could have serious consequences if found out.

Comment: Yes I realise I can't use a single entry one but if I applied for a multi-entry one but then Went to Spain instead of Greece?

Comment: @user2035796 As Relaxed mentioned, you can but it **will** be considered as fraud and you can get caught. In theory it's definitely possible. I'd say in practice it is too, but that's not the ideal path at all.

Comment: That could work (see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26939/can-i-use-my-schengen-visa-for-a-completely-different-purpose-and-entry-point and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9646/does-a-multiple-entry-schengen-visa-allow-visiting-other-schengen-countries-late) but why would you get a Greek multiple-entry visa, with no plans to go to Greece and a residence permit expiring soon? It's even less likely than the single entry visa. As long as your only real need is that one trip to Spain, the only fully legal solution is getting a visa from the Spanish authorities.

Comment: Okay thanks for the responses. Seems like i'm going to have to postpone the trip until I renew my UK Visa, dont want to risk it :(