# Using a multiple-entry business Schengen visa for tourism

Tags: visas, schengen, multiple-entry, change-purpose-of-travel

I am Indian and have a multiple entry Danish business visa and they have requested me to give the itinerary for 16 days even though I have applied for a multiple entry visa.

And do I need to apply for a tourist visa even after having a multiple-entry business visa?

Comment: Who asked you for an itinerary if you already have a visa?

Comment: On using a Schengen visa for another purpose, see e.g. http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26939/can-i-use-my-schengen-visa-for-a-completely-different-purpose-and-entry-point

Comment: Actually my visa was rejected and after appealing 3 months later they granted me a visa and send me a mail saying I need to send a iternary 16 days and insurance and the Guys who booked from Denmark booked for 18 days and they called me today and asked me to submit 16 days itenary.I was planning to stay for 25 days since I have a multiple but looks like these are gone mad..will I have to apply for a tourist visa if I wanna visit Europe even though I have a multiple entry schenhen business visa

Comment: The consulate sent you an email requesting information *after* issuing the visa? What is the maximum stay and validity period of this visa? Have you used that visa before? Have you been in the Schengen area before?

Comment: @sunainatanmurthy: It is still unclear who exactly "they" in your comment refers to.

Comment: They means the Danish embassy....

Comment: As I said when my visa was rejected at first and I appealed and they granted me and sent me an email saying I need to send my passport along with itenary and insurance for the stamping on my passport

Comment: What you can or cannot do with this visa depends on the number of entries but also on the validity period and the maximum stay. Since you don't have a visa, it's difficult to give a specific answer. Note that even if you applied for a multiple-entry visa, the consulate might still decide to issue something else.

Comment: @CGCampbell That's not quite how Schengen visas work. There is no “business” or “tourism” category.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking Schengen visas are valid for all allowed purposes (there is no “business” or “tourism” category like in the US for example) and for all countries in the area. So if you really do get a multiple-entry visa with a long validity, it's fine to reuse it for another purpose after your first trip and you don't need to apply for another visa if the first one is still valid.

Single or two-entry visas are a bit different in this respect, see [Can I use my Schengen visa for a completely different purpose and entry point?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26939/can-i-use-my-schengen-visa-for-a-completely-different-purpose-and-entry-point?lq=1) and [Can I travel to Spain using a Greek Schengen visa even if I don't want to stay in Greece at all?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27672/can-i-travel-to-spain-using-a-greek-schengen-visa-even-if-i-dont-want-to-stay-i?lq=1).

Do note that even a multiple-entry visa might not offer much flexibility as you also need to follow the rules on maximum stay and visa validity.

Now, usually you would submit an application and the consulate would decide what to issue depending on that and on your past history. <s>So it's somewhat strange that they would already have decided they will issue a multiple-entry visa before seeing your itinerary and that *they* would tell you how long your trip should be (are you sure you got that right?).</s> As your subsequent experience showed, consulates can always issue what they want and you won't be sure before you have the actual visa in your passport.

In any case, when applying for a multiple-entry visa, you only have to provide proof of insurance for your first intended trip. You can get insurance for any subsequent trip later.

Comment: Thanks guys for the info....the embassy did tell me that the visa is granted and is for multiple entry for 6 months and since I'm going for the first time ,I think my first trip needs to be for 16 days

Comment: There is no such requirement. I was recently granted a Schengen visa multiple entry (for the Netherlands as well) and I only stayed in Amsterdam for 3 days. There is no "minimum stay" requirement; there is a maximum stay - which is 90 days within any 180 day period.

Comment: These guys just make it a rocket science when it comes to visas

Comment: Guys finally today I got my passport from the embassy and for my disappointment theymy visa was stamped for a small period but actually when I had a phn conversation they told me that i have been given a 6 months multiple entry and today as I see in the passport it say multiple visa under c section but for 25 days ..and I have to report back once I'm.back from The country.....I was thinking if I can talk to the ministry in Copenhagen and request to extend

Comment: Guys pls help em and give me some advise...I leave on sunday

Comment: @sunainatanmurthy Extensions are only granted for serious reasons (say you are stuck in a hospital or something) and not merely because you changed your plans. At this stage, I am afraid that there isn't much you can do but stick to the itinerary you submitted.

Comment: But don't u think its unfair they did so...if so they should mention in the passport single entry..they stamp multiple and its crazy thinking why

Comment: @sunainatanmurthy Maybe but I have seen much worse and that does not really make any difference at this point. Like I wrote earlier, I found it very odd that you would get a multiple-entry visa in this situation so I am not really surprised that they issued something else.

Comment: Also I plan to take Irish or uk visit visa while im in copenhagen..is it possible ?

Comment: @sunainatanmurthy From the Schengen end of things, that's what the number of entries are about. If it says “2” or “multiple”, then you can leave and reenter (provided the visa is still valid and you haven't exhausted the maximum authorized stay). You might also need a UK or Irish visa, though.

Comment: Is it possible that i apply from Copenhagen at the nearest uk or Irish embassy and get the visa..I choose Ireland coz its a bit easy than uk ..and if I have Irish visa I don't need visa to UK

Comment: I would love to have travel for longer period if they gave me a longer period visa..they multiple but asked me for 16 days itenery and the visa is valid untill 31st December... Its like 1 DEC - 31 DEC..now from where do I travel multiple

Comment: It would be something to ask as another question. In principle it might be possible, but with so little time in Denmark and all the difficulties you had to get this visa in the first place, it seems very difficult in practice. Note that according to what you have told us, the visa you got was granted for a 16-day business trip to Denmark. It make sense that it wouldn't allow you to do much more. Your best strategy now is to do this trip and return to India, having used the visa correctly will help you get a better one next time around.

Comment: My company guys has told me will talk to the ministry once I'm there..so I have my fingers crossed

Comment: @sunainatanmurthy I hope for you it will work but I would urge you to buy a return ticket for the right date and be prepared for the possibility that you can't stay longer because the visa you have got does not give you much flexibility. You have been burnt by empty promises and unfulfilled hopes before.

Comment: Yes ur right and I agree with u..I have my return ticket so no worries ,which was done by the company guys in Denmark.. We did all what the embassy requested..