# Schengen 6-month visa. Can I use it again for a different purpose?

Tags: visas, schengen, multiple-entry

I have a multi-entry visa valid until November 14, 2015. I am a private nurse and used it in the middle of last May in Germany for the health of my patient.  We stayed there for one month and went back to our home country.

I want to use it again in August in Portugal as a tourist and to visit my sister there. I will not go there with my employer but there's a remark on my visa that I should be accompanied by my employer.

Can I still use my current visa or do I need to apply again for a new visa?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Schengen type C multi-entry visa then you can.

You can also find the information below at http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/schengen-visa-types/

Copy paste (highlight by me):

- *Single-entry visa allows its holder to enter a Schengen country only once for the certain period of time. Once you leave the certain Schengen country you entered the visa validity expires even if the time period allowed to stay in the country is not over yet.*
- *Double-entry visa applies for the same policy as above mentioned however you are allowed to enter the Schengen country twice meaning that for the certain period of time permitted by your visa you can enter the Schengen country, leave and enter again without any problems. Once you are out of the country for the second time the visa expires.*
- *Multiple-entry visa allows its holder to go in and out of the Schengen country as pleased. However this visa allows its holder to stay in a Schengen Zone for maximum 90 days **within half the year**, starting from the day one crosses the border between a Schengen member country and the non-Schengen member country.*

If you're worried about the purpose of your visit because you originally came for business, this shouldn't matter. Another question here on travel stackexchange https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/38768/28272 mentions that there is no real specific business visa. And a reply from a Schengen helpdesk at https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/permalink/post/18803357 says it's fine.

Comment: There's a remark on my visa that i should be accompanied by my employer. And i will not go with my employer on portugal.

Comment: Hmm well that's a special case then. I haven't heard about that but then I would get an official response before trying.

Comment: Thank you sir. If you can try to look at the copy of my visa; i can send it to you.