# Can I include both business and tourism in one Schengen application?

Tags: tourist-visas, business-travel, schengen-visas

I am going to visit Berlin for business purposes for 3 days.

However, I want to visit other Schengen states as well for 10 days approximately.

On the application checklist, they are asking for flight and hotel reservations.

Do I give them booking details for the whole trip?

If they found that I am mixing business and tourist purposes, are they going to reject my application?

Comment: Not an answer, but a bit of useful info: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26939/can-i-use-my-schengen-visa-for-a-completely-different-purpose-and-entry-point?lq=1 and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38750/using-a-multiple-entry-business-schengen-visa-for-tourism

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking: Yes, you can combine business and tourism in a single visit.

- You have to convince the visa officials that you have a coherent *premise* for your trip. That can be "three days business, and since I'm already there I'll add a little vacation afterwards" or "business meeting on Monday morning, I'll arrive on Saturday and see some museums first."
- Definitely include all the details. They want to know when you will enter the Schengen zone, and when you leave, and where you stay in between. Leaving things out will make them wonder.
- In all likelihood the three days in Germany will be the *main destination* of the trip even if you should spend more than three days in another Schengen country. So you apply for a German visa.
- You have to explain who pays for the trip and why. That can be difficult if part is from your employer and part is from yourself, so set things out clearly.

Comment: I am frequently guilty of this myself: does "yes" respond to the question asked in the title or to one of the questions at the end of the body?