# Visiting my employer in the Netherlands (I work remotely from my home country)

Tags: visas, schengen-visas, netherlands

I'm working remotely for a Dutch-based company in Holland.  I'm their full-time employee, working 9 to 5.  They want me to visit their office this summer.  After looking into at the Schengen visa application form, I'm getting confused about the types of visa.

People are suggesting that I should have a **tourism visa**, but it doesn't make sense to me to have this visa because I'm travelling for an office visit, and will be having some meetings with them.

Some people are saying I should have a **visit visa**, but I haven't seen visit visa information in in the application form.

Some are saying I should have **friend visit visa**.  Again, this doesn't make sense, because they are my employer, not friends.

What type of visa should I apply for?

Comment: Who pay for the travel and the stay? You are paid (as employee) during your stay in Nederland? Why do you think (or your friend think) that Business visa is wrong?

Comment: Obviously that company is going to pay for my expenses. I think Business Visa is for someone who is business man itself. But Im not a business man, Im just their employee.

Comment: Businesses means "business related", "professional", "for work". If you are a businessman or an employee (or a free lancer) do not matter. Often visiting conferences and trade fairs requires a business visa. Note: sometime "businessman" have the "investor visa".

Comment: Thanks for this logical clarification, So should I write in the cover letter and even in the interview about my tourism detail as well, because I'll be attending 3 to 4 days meeting, and then I'll try to visit Amsterdam?

Comment: Yes, in any case get an invitation letter from your company (with names of people who you interact to). About tourism: you can be very short, but it is always better to specify it.

Comment: Thanks for this huge help, How can I rate you?

Comment: You cannot. I didn't answer, just commented (also because I didn't find a source to cite. (But I traveled out of Europe, and on all countries Business Visa were interpreted as I wrote).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I include both business and tourism in one Schengen application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/114923/can-i-include-both-business-and-tourism-in-one-schengen-application)

Comment: Mudassir, it is very common and widely accepted for business travelers to engage in some tourism during a business trip.  You can and should mention this in your application.  The more comprehensive your explanation of how you'll be spending your time is, the better.

Comment: "Business" in this sense is similar to "work", but in the language of visa-speak, "work" means coming to be employed (and paid) in the country you are visiting (here, the Netherlands). Business doesn't mean you are the owner, but implies you are paid in your home country.

Comment: Thank you guys, You guys saved my consultation money. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the application you have to state the main purpose of your journey. On the assumption that the primary reason you’re applying is to spend time with your colleagues in the Dutch office of your employer, it’s a Business visa since this best describes the purpose of your trip and it’s how you’ll be spending the majority of your time. On the other hand, if you planned to spend most of your trip sightseeing, with only a short visit to your employer, then it would be Tourism.
The detailed itinerary that you will submit with your application should make it clear exactly how your time will be split.

Answer (score 2):

The company should send you an invitation letter, based on which you will get a short stay visa (type "C").

There are a few different types of visas, but for business visits, tourism, conferences, etc. you get the "C" visa.  It is just the purpose of your trip, that determines what documentation you need to supply in support of your application.

You should have the following for your application:

- Invitation letter
- A salary statement or certificate of employment which states your name, position, salary and the date you were employed.
- A letter stating that the employer will be paying for the trip (for example, it may state that your flight and hotel are paid for by the employer).

In addition, bring the "usual" documents:

- Bank statement for 6 months which shows your salary deposits
- Passport (must be valid for 6 months)
- A photo (white background)
- The visa application (you can [fill it online](https://consular.mfaservices.nl/schengen-visa/KARHLC))
- Travel insurance
- Any fees

You should apply no later than 15 (working) days before your travel date; but you can apply as early as 3 months.

If this is your first time applying for any Schengen visa, I suggest applying as early as you can as your application may go through additional scrutiny.