# Do I need another schengen visa for Tourism if I have a business Schengen visa in an overlapping time frame?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

As the title says, I have a business Schengen visa from Hungary and I have used it to travel to Budapest. It is a multiple entry visa for 3 months with 30 days of validity in the Schengen area.
I'm traveling to Italy in this 3 month time frame for tourism purpose. VFS hasn't been helpful if I will be able to get a Tourism visa or not. Do I need another tourism visa for the trip to Italy?

Comment: Please see the 'related' panel on the right.

Comment: Sorry, the last related post is quite old. That's why I'm in doubt if that still holds true. Apologies for the duplicate.

Comment: This one isn't so old. Why do you think the rules have changed? There will almost inevitably be *some* element of tourism in most business visits. [Can I include both business and tourism in one Schengen application?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/114923/can-i-include-both-business-and-tourism-in-one-schengen-application) If your *only* purpose of this visit is tourism, I guess you can't use the business visa. You won't be able to demonstrate any business reasons at immigration.

Comment: I have already used the business visa once to enter Hungary. But since this is another trip in an overlapping time to another schengen country, I'm not sure if Italy will grant a visa in the overlapping time frame. I'm not travelling for tourism in the business trip, I've already had the primary trip (to Hungary) as a business trip.

Comment: @WeatherVane "If your only purpose of this visit is tourism, I guess you can't use the business visa": this is incorrect.  A multiple-entry Schengen visa can be used for any allowable purpose on subsequent visits.  There's no such thing as a "business visa" or a "tourist visa," both business visitors and tourists are issued a "short stay visa."

Comment: @phoog that is perhaps what [Factsheet Schengen visa](https://www.lewissilkin.com/en/insights/factsheet-schengen-visa) says, but I didn't quote it because it doesn't elaborate within each visa description.

Answer (score 2):

Italy will not issue a short-stay visa while you have a valid short stay visa issued by another Schengen country.  If the visa is a multiple-entry visa and you have not exhausted the 30 days then you should use your existing visa.