# Can I change my flight dates after I get my Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen, france, multiple-entry

I am an Indian student in the UK. If I already had a single entry Schengen visa and I apply again to the French embassy, will I be issued with multiple-entry?

If I get the visa, but due to a problem, I cannot travel on the intended dates(ones I mentioned on visa form) and decide to travel a month later, will it cause a problem when I travel next. And if I dont exactly follow the itenary that I submitted with my visa application?

As far as dates are concerned. I mean this: Suppose my visa is valid for May-August. When I applied for this visa, my itenary and hotel bookings were for June. But now I decide to travel instead in July. Will there be a problem if I did not take the journey for which I initially applied the visa and take a different journey later instead

Comment: Good performance history helps a lot, but nobody can reliably predict if you will get a multiple entry Schengen.  A legal professional needs to examine your application BEFOREHAND in order to even GUESS.

Comment: You have to describe the variances in detail before anybody can give a meaningful answer.  Please edit to provide the detail before the higher-ups close it as 'unclear what you're asking'...

Comment: Your questions is a bit too broad and open-ended to be answered precisely but you may want to use the site's search function to learn more about Schengen visas, a lot of this has already been covered in other questions.

Comment: @relaxed Edited :)

Answer (score 3):

If you have some plausible explanation for doing that, there is no reason postponing a trip for a few weeks should be an issue. Simply make sure you have all the documentation corresponding to your new itinerary (e.g. airline and accommodation bookings) with you when crossing the border. By contrast, going to the other end of the Schengen area without anything to justify the purpose of your trip *could* be an issue, see [Can I travel to Spain using a Greek Schengen visa even if I don't want to stay in Greece at all?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27672/can-i-travel-to-spain-using-a-greek-schengen-visa-even-if-i-dont-want-to-stay-i/27675#27675) and the other pages mentioned there for a full discussion of a range of scenarios.

But if you don't have the visa yet, it might not make sense to worry about this just yet. As a repeat applicant living in the UK, you do have reasonably good odds of gettting a multiple-entry visa but it's also possible you would still get another single-entry visa with a short validity period, based on the itinerary you submitted with your application and that wouldn't give you much flexibility.

Once you have made several trips to the Schengen area or if you are lucky enough to get a multiple-entry visa with a long validity this time, you will be able to change plans more easily.

Answer (score 2):

As you can read at [Can I use my Schengen visa for a completely different purpose and entry point?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26939/can-i-use-my-schengen-visa-for-a-completely-different-purpose-and-entry-point) for example

> The visa is not specific to a country or purpose, it's valid for all short stays in the Schengen area. It's also perfectly fine to enter the Schengen area through another country

So another country fine, however this [thread](http://www.thaivisa.com/forum/topic/349170-schengen-visa-validity-question/) warns you that the dates can not be changed -- if you intend to travel outside of the validity of your visa, you need to ask for a new one.

Edit: As long as your visa is valid while you are in the Schengen area you should have no problems. However, don't be surprised if you get a visa (single or multi entry doesn't matter) to the exact dates you provided for entry and leave.

Comment: Thanks. But as far as dates are concerned. I mean this: Suppose my visa is valid for May-August. When I applied for this visa, my itenary and hotel bookings were for June. But now I decide to travel instead in July. Will there be a problem if I did not take the journey for which I initially applied the visa and take a different journey later instead