# Schengen Visa - Travel dates issue

Tags: indian-citizens, international-travel, schengen-visas, multiple-entry

My parents will be applying for Schengen visa from India. They will opt for Mutiple entries. 
These are the tentative travel dates to Paris as per the itinerary (Aug 19 to Aug 25). 
Is it that the Visa authorities will only issue visa from Aug 19 to Aug 25 ? What if my travel plan changes after I receive the visa ? Will the visa be invalid?

Comment: Is this their first Schengen (or any) visa application? Typically 1st time applicants would probably be given a single entry visa with the number of days in accordance with the travel itinerary provided with the visa application, and a validity period slightly longer than the travel period to allow for a little flexibility at either end of the planned dates. Your parents may not get a multiple entry visa if their travel plan doesn’t warrant it. Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45800/can-i-change-my-flight-dates-after-i-get-my-schengen-visa

Comment: Thank you so much ! Yes, this is their first Schengen visa. This time they plan to be in France. So if I'm reading between the lines, you are suggesting to stick to the itinerary as far as possible. In future (say after 6 months) if they want to visit Switzerland and Germany, would they need to reapply ?

Comment: If you think plans might change then describe the possible changes in the application. If it's something like "we might stay for an extra week because..." then they will probably give you a visa that covers the possible changes. If it's "we don't know what we are doing so please give us a 3 month visa" they probably won't.

Comment: @Ricky101 Well yes, depending on whether their visa was multiple entry and its expiry date. See https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/read_visa_sticker_en

Comment: I'm planning to stick to single entry with a specific date range.