# Filling in Schengen Visa paperwork: what is my member state of first entry?

Tags: visas, schengen, poland, austria

While filling in the paperwork for a Schengen Visa with the Embassy of Poland, there is a column that asks for the "member state of first entry" to be entered.

My flight has a 2 hour transit layover in Vienna, and then continues on to Warsaw, Poland. Would the member state of first entry be Austria, or Poland?

Comment: its not duplicate I'm not going to trip to another country its my flight condition and I want to stay in transit zone for layover

Comment: @ACTIONGAMER You will not be staying in transit zone since the flight from Vienna to Warsaw is within the Schengen external border so even if the flight is to a different country you're unlikely to encounter immigration control in Poland for this flight.

Comment: so @Karlson what i have to do then ? what will be my first entry member state?

Comment: @ACTIONGAMER Your first entry state is Austria.

Comment: thanx @Karlson another question : still i have to get my visa from Poland embassy for long stay?

Comment: @actiongamer Visa you're supposed to get from the country which is your main destination.  In this case I guess it's Poland.

Answer (score 8):

The "Member state of first entry" will be Austria because that's where you will pass through immigration.

Comment: are you sure about that?if yes which embassy i have to get my visa Austria or Poland

Comment: You are right in applying to the Polish consulate because (I assume) that's where your main destination is. Your passport and visa, however, will be checked at the port of entry, which is Vienna and hence "Member state of first entry" is Austria.

Comment: thanx but please take a look, something similar to me but different answers still confused :(
http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/28942/schengen-visa-issuing-country-and-first-entry-state?rq=1

Comment: The answer there doesn't contradict mine.

Comment: yes it is his visa first entry set for France but he is disconnecting between Germany and France and people said its not a problem.

Comment: Yes, he's in the same situation as you: his visa is issued by France, and his member state of first entry is Germany.