# I have a Schengen visa for Germany. Can I travel via France by car? I would like to spend 2 days in Disney World

Tags: visas, schengen

I have a Schengen visa for Germany. Can I travel via France by car? I would like to spend 2 days in Disney World

Comment: *In principle,* a Schengen visa for the "Schengen States" allows you to travel to any Schengen state. There may be problems if it *looks* as if you misrepresented your itinerary to get the visa, e.g. if you arrive in Finland with a Greek visa. As long as Germany remains the main destination of the trip and you can document that, minor changes to the itinerary are OK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entering France on German issued Schengen Visa (South African passport)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38341/entering-france-on-german-issued-schengen-visa-south-african-passport) and [Should my first trip be to the country which issued my Schengen Visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13362/should-my-first-trip-be-to-the-country-which-issued-my-schengen-visa)